# Matrix lossing Assets type data

Tags: matrix, assets

I have a matrix field with an assets column that it is loosing its data when editing the entry.

It saves fine the first time, but upon returning to edit, the file reference it no longer in the column.

any idea why this could be happening?

using ee v 2.8.1, assets v 2.2.4 and matrix v. 2.5.10

Comment: Updating to Assets 2.3.1 (latest version currently) might resolve this for you. If it does not, contact support@pixelandtonic.com :)

Comment: upgraded and it didn't fix the issue. Sent email to support. thanks.